# error was received while processing Paperclip::Errors::CommandNotFoundError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm sharing the solution I didn't find in any posts in the hopes of saving someone else some time and trouble.

After ImageMagick is correctly installed:

```
$ which convert

$ /opt/local/bin/convert
```

I added `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin/"` to `routes.rb` rather than `development.rb` as recommended in the [paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

If there's any reason not to include `Paperclip.options` in `routes.rb`, I'd like to know!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, [paperclip's documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) recommends to set `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin/"` in the environment config file (development.rb or production.rb for example).